# Ubuntu 22.04 Fresh Install Missing / Unknown File System

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have new huawei D15 laptop that I succesffully dual-booted with Win11 and Ubuntu 22.04.  I have been using it for about a week, installing apps, configuring networks, etc..

**Problem 1**
This morning, I booted my computer and found that grub was missing.
At boot I got the `'minimal BASH like line editing is supported'` error and decided to boot from LiveUSB and use boot-repair to solve the problem.

**Problem 2**
Upon booting from LiveUSB and running boot-repair, I discovered that the boot-repair "Recommended Repairs" option was completely missing.

**Problem 3**
So I opened gparted and discovered that my ubuntu partition, somehow has a completely `unknown file system`

**Additional Info**
This is the paste bin url that was provided by boot repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CjQSSMdrRh/

```
boot-repair-4ppa2056                                              [20230406_0347]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/HUAWEI/CapAgent.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /bootmgr /boot/bcd

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p8: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sda and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sda: /dev/sda already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] from Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.13(1.13) from HUAWEI
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0004,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Linpus lite   HD(2,GPT,a0891d7e-b930-4513-94db-f629dbd637b2,0x92b094,0x2754)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c3514531-5560-444a-a957-0f890181bf62,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c3514531-5560-444a-a957-0f890181bf62,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Boot2101* Huawei Firmware Update Program    HD(1,GPT,c3514531-5560-444a-a957-0f890181bf62,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\HUAWEI\CapAgent.efi)

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
33b99117db23dbcc28808710e91ecfdf   nvme0n1p1/HUAWEI/CapAgent.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
da9defb77e395742a503d0fc04c84cd7   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
c1704cb73f6e86c013777fd089c43b4e   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
b8796e68099026aabcebb8fcf75b21f6   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi
ae8af199ef80311f9cee9de104a15496   nvme0n1p5/Boot/bootx64.efi
62ad2d96df1db720085d1cf4d4e64f4c   nvme0n1p6/Boot/bootx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p5   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p7   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p8   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, bootmgr,    is-winboot
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p8   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p8   : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: B2A13A43-33AE-40DF-9862-E8D1CD1ADE1A
              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048     411647    409600   200M EFI System
nvme0n1p2    411648     444415     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3    444416  252102655 251658240   120G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 252102656  408494427 156391772  74.6G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5 959320064  960368639   1048576   512M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p6 960368640  998117375  37748736    18G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p7 998117376 1000214527   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p8 408496128  959320063 550823936 262.7G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 28.91 GiB, 31037849600 bytes, 60620800 sectors
Disk identifier: A0891D7E-B930-4513-94D9-F629DBD637B2
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sda1       64  9613459  9613396  4.6G Microsoft basic data
sda2  9613460  9623527    10068  4.9M EFI System
sda3  9623528  9624127      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sda4  9625600 60620736 50995137 24.3G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ADATA USB Flash Drive:;
1:32.8kB:4922MB:4922MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:4922MB:4927MB:5155kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:4927MB:4928MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:4928MB:31.0GB:26.1GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:511BS0512HB:;
1:1049kB:211MB:210MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:211MB:228MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:228MB:129GB:129GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:129GB:209GB:80.1GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
8:209GB:491GB:282GB:::;
5:491GB:492GB:537MB:fat32::hidden, diag;
6:492GB:511GB:19.3GB:ntfs::hidden, diag;
7:511GB:512GB:1074MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda         iso9660  2023-02-23-04-13-44-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64 
├─sda1      iso9660  2023-02-23-04-13-44-00               a0891d7e-b930-4513-94d8-f629dbd637b2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sda2      vfat     F7DB-4D56                            a0891d7e-b930-4513-94db-f629dbd637b2 ESP                      Appended2
├─sda3                                                    a0891d7e-b930-4513-94da-f629dbd637b2                          Gap1
└─sda4      ext4     01fb1ac2-5a18-4f50-9f1f-81607d65e917 de059be4-426c-d249-a5aa-32b766bae15e writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     3C7D-A18E                            c3514531-5560-444a-a957-0f890181bf62 SYSTEM                   EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               99caa1c4-2943-459d-836a-c9580fb7853b                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     76E433C1E4338283                     caf074f5-2d89-47e7-a134-f940ac0df386 Windows                  Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     CA10F74610F73851                     2226c7ba-b144-467e-ac16-0afb05a62708 Data                     Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p5 vfat     427E-0752                            a043f57f-fa49-41c0-8d8f-facc10cd1612 WINPE                    Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     24AC80A3AC8070DA                     bd51b383-3158-4d00-882f-54c2e2820935 Onekey                   Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p7 ntfs     96CC7D5ACC7D3619                     654a597e-1277-4f44-8d0d-524528fe7821 WinRE                    Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p8                                               6cc8d589-65a0-4876-a322-f5602e7718c1                          

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail            Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-04-06.4/crash]  22.5G              0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2023-04-06.4/log]    22.5G              0% /var/log
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                123.5M             37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                 53.4G             55% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                                337.1G 94361713839776% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                 99.7M             80% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6                                                  827M             96% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7                                                231.3M             77% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7
/dev/sda1                                                          0            100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 965f78cc-3e37-403a-8d6a-3a932e7ad544 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the MBR.
Additional repair would be performed:  win-legacy-basic-fix
```

**More info**
[image]

Any suggestion to repair the file system of my ubuntu partition I'd rather not loose the set-up progress that I have made.

thanks

Comment: try `configfile (hd0,gpt4)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in the grub shell (minimal bash like). If it doesn't go to the ubuntu grub, then execute `set` command and post here the result.

Comment: @Andra...  i will give first command a try in a moment... but I will need more clarity about runinng `set` command. thanks

Comment: `set` without options just outputs information

Comment: I just added an image of the `set` output to my post

Comment: @Andra  I have been reading about the problem... and it seems that simply repairing grub is insufficient in this case.  The first seems to be repair the partition file system, then repair grub...  any tips on repairing the from file system from LiveUSB... Note: Disk Utility wouldn't allow me to fix the ubuntu partition... greyed out.  but obviously, perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: what about `configfile`? and add the output of `ls` please. My idea how you can deal with the problem is that when you have booted your ubuntu, reinstall grub.

Comment: @Andra  thanks for the assistance.. very much appreciated....  I did some more digging and started from zero... and that's where I found my original mistake.  For anyone who finds this thread.  I neglected to first partition the Win11 Data Disk to make space for my Ubuntu install.  While the dual boot worked initially, it resulted in a corrupt partition table.  Rather trying to piece everything together after the fact.. my solution: burn it all down... start over... the correct way.